# How many even numbers will $99$ dice show if we roll them forever under a certain condition?

Tags: probability, recursion

Consider a six-sided die with numbers from $1$ to $6$. Imagine you have a jar with $99$ of such dice. You throw all dice on the floor randomly. You look at one of the dice on the floor at a time. For each die, you do the following:

- If it landed at an even number $(2,4,6)$, you turn the die so that it lands on the number $1$.
- If the die landed on an odd number $(1,3,5)$, you throw the die up in the air, so it can land on any number.

After you finish doing the above for all dice on the floor, you come back to the first die and repeat the entire process again. You keep on doing this until eternity (for a billion years, let’s say). If I come into the room after a billion years, how many dice on the floor will have even numbers up?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basic rules of the site. Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e its about mathematics and not Mathematica. If that's not your intention, please [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to make it explicitly about Mathematica programming. Include a minimum example of the code you are working on.

Comment: Eternity is not 100000000 years. That's barely the time when dinosaurs ruled the earth. How is that an eternity?

Comment: this is either a trick question, or poorly worded (likely a poor translation ). Literally we only re throw the portion of the dice from the first bullet on each iteration, so the process will stop after a half dozen throws with on average 50/50 odd/even mix.

Comment: Nothing tricky, fairly simple solution, but the question is poorly explained. The solution does not converge to a single value for longer times, so the $10^8$ years are irrelevant. The question should ask either by the average number or for the distribution of numbers and not for the exact number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many even numbers will $99$ dice show if we roll them for eternity under a certain condition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000994/how-many-even-numbers-will-99-dice-show-if-we-roll-them-for-eternity-under-a-c)

Comment: By the way, I propose this as the duplicate even though it’s half an hour older, since the answers in this one all seem to refer to Mathematica, while the other question has a mathematical (albeit short) answer. Perhaps a sort of merge would be better?

Answer (score 3):

OK, its not about Mathematica, but let's make it about using Mathematica to visualize the result, just for fun.

### Analytic

The first run produces some number of `nE` even numbers with probability

```
pe0 = PDF[BinomialDistribution[99, 1/2], nE]
```

Any number from 0 to 99 is possible, justifying the last rule.

[image]

Irrespective of the initial distribution, on equilibrium the probability of changing an *even* number for an *odd* number must be equal to changing from an *odd* to an *even*

```
Solve[pe == (1 - pe)/2, pe]
```

> ```
> {{pe -> 1/3}}
> ```

That means in average `1/3` even, `2/3` odd.

### Simulation

```
start = RandomChoice[Range[6], 99];
BarChart[Apply[Labeled, Reverse[Sort@Tally[start], 2], {1}]]
```

> [image]

```
f = Block[
   {rndIndx = RandomInteger[{1, 99}], new},
   new = If[EvenQ@Part[#, rndIndx], 1, RandomInteger[{1, 6}]];
   ReplacePart[#, rndIndx -> new]
   ] &

reslist = NestList[f, start, 100000];
evol = Transpose[(#/Total[#]) &[Part[Sort@Tally[EvenQ[#]], All, 2]] & /@ reslist];
ListLogLinearPlot[evol, Joined -> True, Epilog -> {Line[{{0, 1/3}, {100000, 1/3}}], Line[{{0, 2/3}, {100000, 2/3}}]},
 PlotRange -> {{1, 100000}, {0, 1}},
 Frame -> True
 ]
```

[image]

### Analysis

As we iterate there will be random fluctuations continuously changing the number of odd and even numbers. The probability of creating a `1` is bigger than any other number. After a couple thousand iterations most of the numbers are `1`

```
Sort@Tally[Last@reslist]
```

> ```
> {{1, 37}, {2, 9}, {3, 10}, {4, 17}, {5, 15}, {6, 11}}
> ```

```
 BarChart[Apply[Labeled, Reverse[%, 2], {1}]]
```

> [image]

And the distribution of even and odd numbers is centred around

```
N[Mean /@ evol]
```

> ```
> {0.666522, 0.333478}
> ```

or 66.65% Odd, and 33.35% even, very close to 2/3 and 1/3 predicted.

The variation about that average is considerable:

```
N[StandardDeviation /@ evol]
```

> ```
> {0.048476, 0.048476}
> ```

so the answer can not be given as a specific number, but as a distribution.

```
SmoothHistogram[evol, 0.01, Frame -> True, 
 Epilog -> {Line[{{1/3, 0}, {1/3, 9}}], Line[{{2/3, 0}, {2/3, 9}}]}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Probability Distribution", 
 FrameLabel -> {"Proportion", "Probability density"}]
```

> [image]

### Conclusion

After a not so long time, provided a couple of thousand iterations have pass, with more than 95% probability you will find a pile with roughly between 57% to 76% odd numbers.
Only the **average** number of odds tends to 2/3 in the limit where the samples goes to infinity. The exact number of a particular instance can not be determined, but the most likely outcome will be 33 even, 66 odds of which a *one* (`1`) will be chosen to be rolled again.

[image]

Comment: +1 just for the sheer length and time spent on the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using Mathematica:

```
Clear[a, n, m, even];
```

For n dice, half are initially even and become odd, the other half are flipped and half of those flipped end up even. So 1/4 are even after the first iteration.

```
even[1] = n/4;
```

For each iteration, all of evens become odd and half of the remainder are even after their flip.

```
even[m_] := even[m] = (n - even[m - 1])/2;
```

Looking at the tailing end of 100 iterations

```
Take[Table[even[m], {m, 1, 100}], -3] // N
```

> {0.333333 n, 0.333333 n, 0.333333 n}

This indicates that the limit is tending to n/3.

```
Clear[even]

even[m_] = 
 a[m] /. RSolve[{a[m] == (n - a[m - 1])/2, a[1] == n/4}, a[m], m][[1]] // 
  ExpandAll
```

> (1/3)*(-1)^(2*m)*n + (1/3)*(-1)^m*
>        2^(-1 - m)*n

Since m is a positive integer, `even[m]` can be restructured to `n/3 (1 + (1/2)*(-1/2)^m)`

```
even[m] == n/3 (1 + (1/2)*(-1/2)^m) //
 Simplify[#, {Element[m, Integers], m > 0}] &
```

> True

```
Limit[n/3 (1 + (1/2)*(-1/2)^m), m -> Infinity]
```

> n/3

For n = 99, after an infinite number of iterations the number of dice with even numbers up is statistically 33.

Answer (score 0):

FOOD FOR THOUGHT:
To better understand these numbers one must consider what these numbers mean.  They are by example as odds are prime numbers which are the truest odds, these numbers as evens are the truest evens.  1,3,5,7,11 etc...  are prime numbers.  As with these numbers they continue forever.  However, prime numbers start out with less numbers than the numbers able to be put on dice but continue to become more often than the numbers able to be put on dice as these numbers increase.  So, half of every one of these even numbers able to be put on dice are 1,2,3,4,5,6,10,15,50 and they continue always having fewer halves of these evens that make odds than halves making evens.  One can find a mathematical way to depict which numbers come next.  Here are my notes:  First of all, though half of every other even is an even, being that half of the even before is an odd.  But as these numbers increase there are fewer and fewer halves of the numbers able to be put on dice that are odds.  And more and more halves of these numbers are evens.  But, 2 fits every definition of a prime number except that it is an even.  Only 1 and itself go into prime numbers.  Yet, 2 goes into all evens and one goes into all whole positive numbers because 2 odds make an even and any amount of evens make an even when added together.  That statement is obvious but if you look deeper that is a knot which ties all numbers together.  Think of negatives.  Negative numbers do not have a beginning but do have an end.  Hence -1 is the last and largest negative.  Negatives are always  bigger than the one before.  As positives being opposites the two must always have an equal and opposite relationship.  Hence there is no largest positive each after being larger than the one before.  It's all about equality considering odds and evens as well.  I'd really like to explain myself as there is a huge knot of infinity that ties all numbers together.  Some of this might be out of place but I think this will better explain this question better.

Comment: I'm having trouble following your answer: particularly the bits where you talk about numbers larger than 6, and where you say that 2 fits the definition of every prime number except that is it even (being even doesn't disqualify 2 from being prime, it just makes it unique amongst primes).